# Clicking on JLayeredPane clicks on behind button

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

[image]

[image]

As you can see when I click on red area still back button (start seq) clicks, I am using the `JLayeredPane` here.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code ?

Comment: layeredPanel.add(expandedPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 10);
    layeredPanel.add(bannerPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 20);
    layeredPanel.add(cameraPopupPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 30);
    layeredPanel.add(videoPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 40);
    layeredPanel.add(sidePanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 50);<br/>expandedPanel is the panel which you can seen in red and sidePanel contains button

Comment: Please add the code to your original post so we can read it properly.  The issue is probably with your mouse and/or key listeners, so make sure to add those as well.

Comment: @Leet-Falcon  The code that would be *most* optimal would be a [mcve].  Type `[mcve]` in a comment to get it 'auto-expanded to that title and link.

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see when I click on red area still back button (start seq) clicks,

What is the point of the red area?

Add a MouseListener to the red area. Then it should receive the MouseEvent, not the component below it.

Comment: Same problem for me. In my own example, the red area is just a place holder and will be filled later with labels and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Useing below code you can solve the above problem:

```
    layeredPanel.add(bannerPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 20);

    layeredPanel.add(expandedPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 10);

    layeredPanel.add(cameraPopupPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 30);

    layeredPanel.add(videoPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 40);

    layeredPanel.add(sidePanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER + 50);
```

**layeredPanel** is a instance of JLayeredPane